# PHP script inserting data into db return success on execution but record is not inserted in db?

Tags: php, mysql, apache, phpmyadmin, apache2

**strong text**Below is the code used for inserting a record into the database. Script is getting executed where as the record is not getting inserted into database but the php script is getting executed with out any fail. Please help me with this.

```
<?php
$servername = "xxx.xx.x.xxx";
$username = "usr";
$password = "pwd";
$dbname = "Dbname";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
     die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$postdata = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
$tablename = "tablename";
function guidv4($data)
{
    assert(strlen($data) == 16);

    $data[6] = chr(ord($data[6]) & 0x0f | 0x40); // set version to 0100
    $data[8] = chr(ord($data[8]) & 0x3f | 0x80); // set bits 6-7 to 10

    return vsprintf('%s%s-%s-%s-%s-%s%s%s', str_split(bin2hex($data), 4));
} 
if(is_array($postdata)){

    $sql = "INSERT INTO ".$tablename." (id, ssid, address, lat, lng, state, country, city, cat, subcat, sname, createdAt,pincode) VALUES ";

    $valuesArr = array();
    foreach($postdata as $row){
                    //$loc = explode(", ", $row['loc']);
                    //$lat = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $loc[0]);
                    //$lng = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $loc[1]);         
                    $id = guidv4(random_bytes(16));
                    //$id = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $row['id']);
                    $ssid = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $row['sname']);
                    $address = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $row['address']);                   
                    $lat = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $row['lat']);
                    $lng = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $row['lng']);
                    $state = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $row['state']);
                    $country = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, "India");
                    $city = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $row['city']);
                    $cat = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $row['cat']);
                    $subcat = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $row['subcat']);
                    $sname = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $row['sname']);
                    $createdAt = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $row['createdAt']);
                    $pincode = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $row['pincode']);                   
                    $valuesArr[] = "('$id', '$ssid', '$address', '$lat', '$lng', '$state', '$country', '$city', '$cat', '$subcat', '$sname', '$createdAt','pincode')";


    }

    $sql .= implode(',', $valuesArr);

    $conn->query($sql) or exit(mysql_error()); 
}



$conn->close();
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the $valuesArr array elements are not being concatenated correctly

You should separate the PHP variables from the text, using the concatenation operator ".", like so:

```
  $valuesArr[] = "('" . $id ."', '" .$ssid . "', '" . $address ."', '" . $lat ."', '" . $lng . "', '" $state . "', '" . $country . "', '" . $city . "', '" . $cat . "', '" . $subcat ."', '" . $sname . "', '" . $createdAt . "','pincode')";
```